# How to align divs horizontally with html?

Tags: css, html, overflow

I need to do a toolbar that consists of a Left-arrow button, a set of image buttons then a Right-arrow button

My requirements are:

- the toolbar needs to be on one row
- the toolbar needs to be centered horizontally
- the set can have many image buttons (N is unknown)
- when the window is too small in width the middle div should hide the image buttons that don't fit

To center everything horizontally I found this to work well on chrome:

```
<div style="display:-webkit-box; -webkit-box-pack:center; -webkit-box-align:center;" class="toolbar">
    <button>LEFT</button>
    <div style="overflow:hidden;">
        <button style="height:72px">1</button>        
        <button style="height:72px">2</button>        
        <button style="height:72px">3</button>
        <button style="height:72px">4</button>        
        <button style="height:72px">5</button>
        <button style="height:72px">6</button>        
        <button style="height:72px">7</button>        
        <button style="height:72px">8</button>
        <button style="height:72px">9</button>
    </div>
    <button>RIGHT</button>
</div>
```

But unfortunately the box parameters breaks the overflow:hidden style that is necessary if the middle set becomes too big to fit everything.

So is there another way of centering everything horizontally ?

Comment: Buttons:`position:relative;float:left` add a margin so the button aren't compressed;outer div `margin:0 auto`

Comment: I suppose that the LEFT and RIGHT buttons will allow the user to scroll through any hidden image/buttons?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the elements are not floated, you can use text-align: center, along with display: inline block.

```
<div style="text-align:center;" class="toolbar">
    <button style="display: inline-block;">LEFT</button>
    <div style="overflow:hidden; display:inline-block;">
        <button style="height:72px">1</button>        
        <button style="height:72px">2</button>        
        <button style="height:72px">3</button>
        <button style="height:72px">4</button>        
        <button style="height:72px">5</button>
        <button style="height:72px">6</button>        
        <button style="height:72px">7</button>        
        <button style="height:72px">8</button>
        <button style="height:72px">9</button>
    </div>
    <button style="display: inline-block;">RIGHT</button>
</div>
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QJKQ/)

Comment: inline-block breaks the overflow:hidden that is necessary

Comment: if you set a height in the container, it does not influenciate. http://jsfiddle.net/madaaah/3QJKQ/2/

Comment: yes never mind my last comment I thought you meant display:inline

Comment: but the problem is that if you add more and more middle buttons then at some point my 3 elements (left, set, right) will be split in 3 rows...  http://jsfiddle.net/4vEsS

Comment: just a note... you really shoul put this styles in a separated file, if that's an option for you... Then, you could avoid repetition of code and improve maintainability.

Comment: You would need to set a max-width to fix that. about 80 or 70% should do. But then, you would have croped content.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this I'm not sure exactly what is best for you.

First be sure to set the width of your div element that contains the buttons. other wise it will default to 100% and the margin:0 auto won't work;

something like this

```
<style>
.horizantalAlign{
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
<div class="horizantalAlign">
    <button style="height:72px">1</button>        
    <button style="height:72px">2</button>        
    <button style="height:72px">3</button>
    <button style="height:72px">4</button>        
    <button style="height:72px">5</button>
    <button style="height:72px">6</button>        
    <button style="height:72px">7</button>        
    <button style="height:72px">8</button>
    <button style="height:72px">9</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers not met the condition

> when the window is too small in width the middle div should hide the image buttons that don't fit

```
overflow:hidden requires size
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:10%; max-width:10%; white-space:nowrap;
            max-height:72px; height:72px">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VzyRm/

Comment: Yes the height is fixed at 72px (sorry I forgot in my original)
But for the width I want the width to be as big as possible.
in other words max-width: 100% - width of both buttons LEFT and RIGHT

Comment: I see, but you will need some sort of size, if you want to hide some eq. http://jsfiddle.net/VzyRm/1/

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow:hidden` will only work if you give it a set width and height.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:213px; height:73px;">
```

View the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMNXK/1/)

Comment: That's the problem I don't know the width as it can be resized by the user

Comment: You'll need to establish some sort of size. What do you want it to be in relation to the page or parent element? 80% total size to allow for the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The "margin: 0 auto" inspired me to find a solution.  thanks

I am using a table instead of a div and it's then working well

http://jsfiddle.net/G3Vu6/4/

```
<div style="" class="toolbar">
<table style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style=""><button>LEFT</button></td>
        <td style="" >
            <div style="overflow:hidden;max-height:72px">
                <button style="height:72px">1</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">2</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">3</button>
                <button style="height:72px">4</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">5</button>
                <button style="height:72px">6</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">7</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">8</button>
                <button style="height:72px">9</button>
                <button style="height:72px">1</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">2</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">3</button>
                <button style="height:72px">4</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">5</button>
                <button style="height:72px">6</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">7</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">8</button>
                <button style="height:72px">9</button>
                <button style="height:72px">1</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">2</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">3</button>
                <button style="height:72px">4</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">5</button>
                <button style="height:72px">6</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">7</button>        
                <button style="height:72px">8</button>
                <button style="height:72px">9</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><button style="">RIGHT</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Try playing with the splitters in fiddler and you will see how it reacts beautifully.